# ActionScript 3.0: Trivial setter calls getter three different times. Why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, properties, setter, getter

Take the following code:

```
private var m_iWidth:int;
[Bindable]
public function get width():int
{
    Alert.show("getter");
    return m_iWidth;
}
private function set width(pValue:int):void
{
    Alert.show("setter");
    m_iWidth = pValue;
}

private function someFunction(pWidth:int):void
{
    width = pWidth;
}
```

The output of `width = pWidth;` is:

```
getter
setter
getter
getter
```

Please explain.  Thanks.

Comment: The width property is Bindable - do you have something binding to it?  That could explain the last two getter calls.

When the property is set, the code first calls the getter to see if the value is different - if it's the same, then the setter isn't called.  At least, that's what I believe I've observed.

Comment: @BillTurner Thanks, I think that's it.  Move your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When the property is set, the code first calls the getter to see if the value is different.  If it's the same then the setter isn't called (explains the first get/set pair).

2) If the property is bound, after it's set any access will call the getters (explains the last two getter calls)